# Excel 2010 VBA Macro quits with no error in middle of execution after Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Tags: excel, vba, insert

For some reason, my macro just stops execution, but with no errors right after executing the line:

```
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

It correctly pushes the contents down a line, but I do not see any error message.

Using F8 to execute the macro step by step, that one line has the yellow arrow to its left immediately before execution, I hit F8, it does the insertion, and there's no yellow arrow pointing to the next line as I would expect. Nor is there any error dialog.

Even using the Debug menu's Step Into, after doing the Insertion, the VBA editor just acts as though it has completed execution of the entire macro.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Edit: Here's the full script. It dies on completing the Insert for the Apr worksheet, never going on to the next line (*Range("APR_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName*):

```
Sub Add_New_SPP_LINE()

Dim StartPoint As Worksheet
Dim resp As Long

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Account Info").Activate
Set StartPoint = ActiveSheet
resp = vbYes
resp = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you want to enter a new SPP Line Name now?" _
, Buttons:=vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
If resp = vbYes Then
'Enter new client name
    NewSPPLineName = InputBox("Enter new SPP Line Name:")
  'Add account to Account Info table
    Worksheets("Account Info").Activate
    Range("ACCT_INFO_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("ACCT_INFO_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to APR table
    Worksheets("Apr").Activate
    Range("APR_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("APR_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to MAY table
    Worksheets("May").Activate
    Range("MAY_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("MAY_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to JUN table
    Worksheets("Jun").Activate
    Range("JUN_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("JUN_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to JUL table
    Worksheets("Jul").Activate
    Range("JUL_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("JUL_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to AUG table
    Worksheets("Aug").Activate
    Range("AUG_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("AUG_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to SEP table
    Worksheets("Sep").Activate
    Range("SEP_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("SEP_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to OCT table
    Worksheets("Oct").Activate
    Range("OCT_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("OCT_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to NOV table
    Worksheets("Nov").Activate
    Range("NOV_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("NOV_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to DEC table
    Worksheets("Dec").Activate
    Range("DEC_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("DEC_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to JAN table
    Worksheets("Jan").Activate
    Range("JAN_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("JAN_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to FEB table
    Worksheets("Feb").Activate
    Range("FEB_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("FEB_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName
  'Add account to MAR table
    Worksheets("Mar").Activate
    Range("MAR_END").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("MAR_END").Offset(-1, 0) = NewSPPLineName

''End cycling through the sheets
'Resume at original position
    StartPoint.Select
Else
MsgBox "New account not entered at this time.", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's hard to solve the problem without seeing the entire subroutine.

Comment: OK; added full code. Thanks.

Comment: What is the corresponding range for `APR_END`?

Comment: It's `=Apr!$A$343`

FWIW, `ACCT_INFO_END` is =`'Account Info'!$A$361`

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Are you sure there isn't a breakpoint there, or it isn't triggering some kind of worksheet change event?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.

Definitely no breakpoint, 

`WHATEVER_END` is at the bottom of a table in each worksheet, so all of the columns get calculated from row 12 down to three hundred-whatever. I don't see any kind of worksheet change event that would have been executed.

Comment: FWIW, when I've come back to this, if I change Calculation mode to Manual, run it, and go back to Automatic, it's fine. @dwirony, I don't know if that supports your theory about a "worksheet change event."